# What's the difference between rangeSets and rangeSet in SolrIndexedProperty type?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

While creating a new search facet in Hybris 5.7 I've found that in SolrIndexedProperty type there is an attribute called `rangeSet` and there is also a many-to-many relation called `SolrIndexedProperty2SolrValueRangeSetRelation` between SolrIndexedProperty and SolrValueRangeSet.

What's the difference between these fields? None of them is deprecated or something. Which one should I use in order to create my own facet with particular value ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have already find the answer for your question. Still adding my understanding just in case...

A **SolrValueRangeSet** is a collection of related **SolrValueRange**. 
There are two different fields in hybris to support **rangeSet** and **rangeSets**.

One can add a SolrValueRangeSet or a Collection of SolrValueRangeSet to a SolrIndexedProperty to support one-2-many or one-2-many-2many property range values. You can consider the later as the enhancement over the prior.

If you want to allow multi facet ranges for different values you can use rangeSets as shown in below example

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrValueRangeSet;name[unique=true]; qualifier;    type; solrValueRanges(&rangeValueRefID)
                               ;priceRange-USD   ; PriceRangeUSD;  double; usd-range1, usd-range2
                               ;priceRange-EUR   ; PriceRangeEUR;  double; eur-range1, eur-range2
```

**SolrValueRange** : Define related price range values like below

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrValueRange; &rangeValueRefID;s olrValueRangeSet(name)[unique=true]; name[unique=true]; from; to
 ;usd-range1;priceRange-USD;    Rating 1;  0; 50
 ;usd-range2;priceRange-USD;    Rating 2; 50; 100
 ;eur-range1;priceRange-EUR;    Rating 1;  0; 120
 ;eur-range2;priceRange-EUR;    Rating 2; 120; 300
```

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty; name[unique = true];rangeSets(name)
                                 ; price range; priceRange-USD , priceRange-EUR
```